# Ruby on Rails: Why my class extension is not recognized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In `views/products/list.html.erb` I use:

```
<%= product.power.power_in_kw.to_kw if ... %>
```

`to_kw` is defined in `lib/my_extensions.rb` along with other methods:

```
class Symbol
  def pluralize
    to_s.pluralize.to_sym
  end
end

class BigDecimal
  def to_kw
    number_to_currency(self, :unit => "kw", :format => "%n%u", :precision => 1)
  end
end

class Float
  def to_dollar
    number_to_currency(self)
  end
end
```

`config/environment.rb` has the following line at the end:

```
require 'my_extensions'
```

However, I got the following error:

```
undefined method `to_kw' for #<BigDecimal:2704620,'0.555E2',8(8)>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: `pluralize` used to work. Then I added `to_kw` and `to_dollar` and it started to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` in your `BigDecimal` and `Float`:

```
class BigDecimal
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  def to_kw
    number_to_currency(self, :unit => "kw", :format => "%n%u", :precision => 1)
  end
end

class Float
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  def to_dollar
    number_to_currency(self)
  end
end
```

I think the error `undefined method to_kw` is caused by the undefined method `number_to_currency`.

Comment: Even if this solves the immediate problem, it doesn't seem okay to add 7 instance methods to every single float or bignumber that ever exists that don't even act on the relevant instance :/ Also, the child method being undefined doesn't cause an error on the parent method being undefined in the backtrace. Ruby's a weee bit smarter than that.

Comment: Yeah, if I had this issue, I would define a view helper method instead of extending these classes, but it's beyond this question. Also, I'm wondering why the error says undefined `to_kw` while not `number_to_currency`, I haven't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been hours since you submitted this, but these functions might work once you restart your app. Items in `lib` generally are not reloaded automatically like those in `app`, so changes made will not be reflected in the application until performing a full restart.

Just throwing it out there :)

I'm also going to point out that, once you have these methods up and running, they probably will not work immediately. This is because your views are defined in the context of all of the Rails view helpers, like `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper`, which defines `number_to_currency`. Your extension in `lib`, however, is not defined in such a context, and therefore cannot access those helpers.

`ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper.number_to_currency` might be more likely to work as expected.